# App is not working in background on iOS 10.1.1

Tags: ios

I am working on chatting/calling app. To make it work in background mode I've enabled these modes:
[image]

It is working very fine with iOS 9.3.4, iOS 10.
Working means it is receiving messages, calls, responding to server when in background, even though there is no call is in progress.

When I run it on iPhone6 with iOS 10.1.1, it is stopping responding when enters in background.

Anyone faced this anytime? Any workaround found?

I am using **Xcode8.2 Beta**

I also tried enabling **Background Fetch** mode, but didn't helped!

### UPDATE

It is working in background **only when any call is in progress** on iOS 10.1.1.

Comment: You should only need to Voip mode for your app, but you need make sure that you have a Voip connection before your apps goes to the background.

Comment: It is having active VoIP connection (SIP server) while entering background.

Comment: @rckoenes: audio, airplay mode I added to show red pulsing status bar while voice call is going in background, it's working on previous iOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I gone through various reads on net, it says that **iOS10 is stopped supporting for background app execution for VoIP apps**.
To run VoIP apps in background, there is no way.

My ap was running in background on iOS10 was because I was building it against iOS9 SDK on Xcode 7.

Only one thing we can do is use **PushKit Framework** and get VoIP silent notifications to awake the app in background!